# What will be the candidate key and why? Please refer question

Tags: relational-database

Consider a relation R(ABCDEG)

The functional dependencies are given below:
AB->C
AC->B
AD->E
B->D
C->A
E->G
Determine the candidate key(s) for the relation R.

Options:
A. AB, AC and C
B. AB and AC
C. AB and C
D. C  only

Comment: I've added the [homework] tag based on the wording of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Towards the bottom of this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model
There is an algorithm that will give you the answer.